# Should I switch MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade

A friend of mine gave me a MacBook Pro that is two generations newer than mine, but is of the lower configuration. Should I switch over to that?

My current MacBook Pro is the early-2011 model with Intel Core i7-2620M processor. I have retrofitted it with 8GB of DDR3-1333 RAM and 480GB Intel SSD 520 Series.

Trips to processor spec comparison and benchmark databases gave me indecisive results.

The one my friend gave me is the early 2012 model with i5-3210M processor. I want to install 16GB of DDR3-1600 RAM and move the SSD over if I do make the switch.

My question is: does it make sense for me to switch computers? And will the newer computer accept my retrofitting parts? Also about the old computer, will a 256GB Kingston SSDNow drive (after the Intel SSD is removed) make a good system drive for a backup machine?

I am a iOS developer that does not play games, and I venture into the virtual machine world very frequently. This is my use pattern.

Comment: What would make you switch? the "old" looks perfectly fine to me as is. Keep both, use one with multiple OS X versions so you can test stuff on it, and as back up in case the new one craps out.

Comment: @Buscar웃 The old one have a few minor dings and dents on it (after almost 4 years of use you gotta have those) and very significant wear and tear.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Also if I switch to use the new one as my main computer the hard drive is moved over (I am not copying data so it is all just a hard drive transplant.) Testing would be difficult as remote debugging is a b**** in Xcode (although I do appreciate the possibilities it opens to me, since I am a developer after all.) Using it as a server is not an option as I have a perfectly good vSphere-based server that virtualizes OS X, and is really beefy.

Comment: as for the exterior, I can probably tell what I had for lunch like a week ago :) and as for moving stuff over Apple has the Migration assistant, so no brainier.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Well even Migration Assistant is coping stuff. I am just transplanting drives to save time.

Comment: I assume you made sure the organ and the patient are compatible.

Comment: @Buscar웃 The new machine is receiving 16GB (2x8GB) DDR3-1600 memory sticks and the 480GB Intel SSD 520 Series drive. Those should work.